# Highcharts 4.0.4 Export Issue on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

I am using Highcharts 4.0.4. I have made some changes to export feature by applying the following code:

```
exporting: {
              buttons: {
                          contextButton: {
                                            enabled: false
                                        },
                                        exportButton: {
                                            text: 'Download',
                                            menuItems: Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.splice(2)
                                        },
                                        printButton: {
                                            text: 'Print',
                                            onclick: function () {
                                                this.print();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
```

The above code shows the Print and Download button instead of default export button. The print button performs the print function, while the download button shows the drop down to export JPG, PNG, SVG etc.

This code is working fine on Chrome and Firefox but not on IE 10, any idea what I am doing wrong here? Somehow Highchart's default export feature is working fine but this updated code is not working.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Any errors in console? What exactly doesn't work? Buttons don't show up? Exporting doesn't create image? Or printing doesn't work? Please, be more specific.

Comment: Printing is working fine, and exporting button is showing up properly, it is just when I click on Download PNG or any other format, it does not download anything.

Comment: One more thing, I have rendered that Highchart graph in an iframe, therefore those buttons are part of iframe. Is it due to iframe? If so, how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Try to update to the newest exporting/highcharts 4.1, and let me know if this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryazfran/ works properly? In my IE10 (Windows 7) exporting is triggered.

Comment: i tried to run this fiddle on ie10, but it didnt export anything.

Comment: which version of IE10 ?

Comment: Hey Sebastian, what version do you have, I have posted the reason why it was not working at my end. Some how it is not just working on 10.0.9200.17183. Whats your IE version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some how the export feature when running from iframe is not working on IE version 10.0.9200.17183. I tried it on some other versions like IE 10.0.9200.16xxx version and it is working fine, it is also working on IE 11. Strange, but yes this is whats happening.

Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I had seen your example on jsfiddle.net/ryazfran

And it is working fine for me on IE8. But I am not able to see the source code...
as it is only a show example...

Can you please post the jsfiddle example with its source code of highcharts...

Actually the code I am using is not working on IE and I am not able to figure out why it is not working...

here is the detailed problem of mine, I also tried latest highcharts 4.1.1, and it is not working on IE 8

http://www.coderanch.com/t/646332/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/Internet-Explorer-modified-page-prevent

Comment: Hey, I have read somewhere that IE8 has some issues with highcharts. You should ask them directly I think.